# PHP upcasting object

Tags: php, oop, upcasting

can I upcast an object to it's parent object?

Example Code

```
class ClassA {
  public function foo(){
    echo get_class($this);
  }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
  public function foo(){
    echo get_class($this); // prints ClassB :)
    parent::foo();         // prints ClassB / I want ClassA :(
  }
}

$B = new ClassB();
$B->foo();
```

is it possible in PHP;

In my scenario I'm building ClassB and I want to overide function ClassB::Foo() to extend its behavior and then handle the control back to it's parent function ClassA::Foo() but the code breaks because it is now an object of ClassB. Plz don't blame me about "code smells" because I now that its ugly! ClassA is out of my control... :-)

Comment: Well, why don't just try?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `__CLASS__` [Magic Constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). It returns the class name that you are currently in, regardless of any inheritance going on.

Comment: I actually want to cast the object to its parent. Above code was an example.. Thanx