# Suggested methods losing in PhpStorm when a subclass is implemented

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have the following class structure

[image: Class Structure]

I'm using Symfony2's service to manage the `BaseHandler` and `BaseManager` classes

```
class BaseHandler implements IHandler
{
    /**
     * @var IManager
     */
    protected $manager;

    ...

    public function setManager(IManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }
    ...
}
```

All works fine, but the problem is when I try to use some methods of `SpecializedManager` class and the PhpStorm's suggestions doesn't show their methods, only methods belonging to `IManager`.

For example in my controller

```
public function indexAction(){
    $handler = $this->get('appbundle.handler.specialized_handler');
    $items = $this->manager->mySubClassMethod(); // PHPStorm shows warning
    ...
}
```

I don't know how to set in the handler subclass the annotation of var `manager` to change to something like this `@var SpecializedHandler $manager`, neither another alternative ways for methods appear in the suggestions.

NOTE: the base class or extended for multiples specialized subclasses.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105260/php-upcasting-object) SO question.

Comment: You may need to use intermediate variable (`$manager = $this->manager; $manager->mySubClassMethod()`) which you can typehint via inline `@var` as you have suggested. Another approach (better one, as it relies on PHPDoc alone) is to re-declare `$manager` property in current/parent class via `@property` (must be located in PHPDoc for that class). All of this because with PHPDoc (and PhpStorm's static analysis) you can type hint only 1st-level objects (`e.g. `$this`, `$manager` etc) and cannot do n-level (`$this->manager` etc).

Comment: There also other approaches like: introduce `getManager()` method in this/parent class which will contain correct `@return` tag and use it instead of `$this->manager` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using PHPStorm, you might install the Symfony2 plugin for PHPStorm: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219?pr=phpStorm

With this plugin installed (and enabled on the project), you should automatically have full auto completion on services.